samba-tool GPO scripts
I have a Samba server set up as a secondary domain controller and an Active Directory server as the primary domain controller. My goal is to deploy a startup script to run on Windows clients in a specific Organizational Unit (OU=HR).
I used the following command to add the startup script:
samba-tool gpo manage scripts startup add {GPO_UID} script.ps1

This created a manifest file, and copied the script to the SYSVOL folder. However, the script does not seem to execute on the clients. The script is supposed to write a file to C:\, but no new file is created.
What I have done so far:

Verified that the script exists in the correct path in SYSVOL. (Where it copied not Policies)
Ensured the GPO is linked to the correct OU (OU=HR).
Checked the script for errors and manually ran it on a client to confirm it works.
Ensured the gpupdate command was run on the client to apply the updated policies.

PS: I cannot see the startup script whet I open Group Policy Management Editor on Windows Active Directory Server since I added it using samba-tool.
Despite this, the script does not run at startup as expected.
Additional Info:

Samba version: 4.17.12-Debian
Windows client version: latest Windows 11
The script is a PowerShell script with permissions to write to C:\.

Can someone help me troubleshoot why the startup script is not being executed? I can provide more details if needed.
